# Sum in Mathematica gives extra "+List"

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I am just doing the following sum over a list

```
t = Table[i^2, {i, 10}]
Sum[t[[i]], {i, 0, 4}]
```

However, the output is

```
30 + List
```

which I have no idea where does the "+ List" come from. Does anyone have the same problem and how to solve that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

List indices start from $1$ in Mathematica. `t[[0]]` corresponds to the `Head` of `t` instead, which in your case is `List`. See the second point in the *Details* section of the [documentation for `Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)):

> Part 0 of an expression is its head.

So your sum with index starting from $0$ corresponds to:

```
Part[t, 0] + Part[t, 1] + Part[t, 2] + Part[t, 3] + Part[t, 4]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
List + 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 == List + 30
```